# Проверка в функциях переменных из класса Python Tkinter

Tags: python, ооп, функции, tkinter

Я делаю текстовой редактор на *Tkinter*, в котором делаю функции для работы с файлами.
У меня есть класс с переменными, в которые заносятся файлы через `askopenfilename()` во время работы определенных функций.

Но в моем коде не корректно работают операторы сравнения значения переменных, которые находятся в классе.
Когда в одной функции файл записывается в переменную из класса, его значение не получается проверить в другой функции:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import os


# VARIABLES
class class_file:
    file_open = None
    file = None


# FUNCTIONS

def save_file_as(class_file, *args):
    class_file.file_open = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*")])

    class_file.file = open(class_file.file, "w")
    class_file.file.write(Textedit.get(1.0, END))
    class_file.file.close()
    window.title(os.path.basename(class_file.file) + " - Editor")
    return class_file.file_open and class_file.file

def open_file(*args):
    class_file.file_open = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*")])

    if class_file.file_open is not None and class_file.file_open != '':
        window.title(os.path.basename(class_file.file_open) + " - Editor")

        Textedit.delete(1.0, END)
        class_file.file = open(class_file.file_open, "r")
        Textedit.insert(1.0, class_file.file.read())
        class_file.file.close()
        return class_file.file_open and class_file.file

def new_file(*args):
    window.title("Untitled - PySider Editor")
    Textedit.delete(1.0, END)
    class_file.file_open = None
    class_file.file = None
    return class_file.file_open and class_file.file

def save_file(*args):
    if class_file.file_open and class_file.file == None:
        save_file_as()

    elif class_file.file_open and class_file.file != None:
        class_file.file = open(class_file.file_open, "w")
        class_file.file.write(Textedit.get(1.0, END))
        class_file.file.close()
        return class_file.file_open and class_file.file

    else:
        print("error")

def close_file(*args):
    window.title("Editor")
    Textedit.delete(1.0, END)
    class_file.file_open = None
    class_file.file = None
    return class_file.file_open and class_file.file


# MAIN
window = Tk()

# Window
window.title("Editor")
window.geometry('1250x680')
window["bg"] = "#333"

# Top menu
menu = Menu(window)
# File
file_items = Menu(menu)
file_items.add_command(label='New File                         Ctrl+N', command=new_file)
file_items.add_command(label='Open File                        Ctrl+O', command=open_file)
file_items.add_command(label='Close File                        Ctrl+W', command=close_file)
file_items.add_command(label='Close All                                ')
file_items.add_command(label='Save                               Ctrl+S', command=save_file)
file_items.add_command(label='Save All                                 ')
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_items)
window.config(menu=menu)

# Text
Textframe = Frame(window)
Textframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
Textedit = Text(Textframe, bg="#333", fg="white", font=('Arial', 14), insertbackground="white", insertwidth=3, wrap=WORD)  
Textedit.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

window.mainloop()
```

Здесь когда переменные `file_open` и `file` равны `None`, это не получается проверить, будто они равны чему то другому. Из-за этого при выполнении функции `save_file` ничего не происходит.

В функции `save_file` я добавил оператор `else`, при его выполнении выводится `"error"`. Когда `else` выполнился, я подумал, что условия предыдущих операторов не соответствует, и добавил `return`. Но от этого ничего не изменилось.

Помогите мне понять в чем тут дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема в том, что вам надо работать с экземпляром класса.

Я вам предложу:

1  Замените имя класса и создайте его экземпляр

```
...

#class class_file:
class ClassFile: 
    file_open = None
    file = None
    
...

class_file = ClassFile()
print(f'func main: {class_file.file_open}, {class_file.file}')

window.mainloop()
```

2 В функциях, которые вы будете тестировать, вставьте

```
print(f'func <name_func>: {class_file.file_open}, {class_file.file}')
```

чтобы вам было понятно, с какими значениями вы оперируете.

3 `return class_file.file_open and class_file.file`
в ваших функциях не нужны, если вам надо изменить
`class_file.file_open` или `class_file.file` -
просто измените его, например, так: `class_file.file_open = None`

4 подумайте о смысле проверки условий, например зачем

```
if class_file.file_open is not None and class_file.file_open != '':
```

если достаточно - `if class_file.file_open:`

`...`

---

**Update**

> Мне нужно написать такие функции, чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на Save в меню, выполнялась функция save_file. И далее если какой либо файл был уже открыт и переменные file_open и file не равны None, файл просто сохранялся. А если эти переменные равны None, например когда редактор запустился, и выполнилась функция save_file появлялось окно asksaveasfilename() - Сохранить как

я не сильно следовал вашим требованиям, но внес некоторые изменения. Проверьте:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import os


#class class_file:
class ClassFile: 
    file_open = None
    file = None


# FUNCTIONS

#def save_file_as(class_file, *args):
def save_file_as(*args):
    class_file.file_open = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*")])
    print(f'1 def save_file_as(*args): {class_file.file_open}, {class_file.file}')
    
#    class_file.file = open(class_file.file, "w")
    class_file.file = open(class_file.file_open, "w")                     # + file_open
    
    class_file.file.write(Textedit.get(1.0, END))
    class_file.file.close()
#    window.title(os.path.basename(class_file.file) + " - Editor")
    window.title(os.path.basename(class_file.file_open) + " - Editor")
#?    return class_file.file_open and class_file.file

def open_file(*args):
    class_file.file_open = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("All Files", "*.txt*")])
    print(f'1 def open_file(*args): {class_file.file_open}, {class_file.file}')

    if class_file.file_open is not None and class_file.file_open != '':
        window.title(os.path.basename(class_file.file_open) + " - Editor")

        Textedit.delete(1.0, END)
        class_file.file = open(class_file.file_open, "r")
        Textedit.insert(1.0, class_file.file.read())
        class_file.file.close()
        print(f'2 def open_file(*args): {class_file.file_open}, {class_file.file}')
# ?        return class_file.file_open and class_file.file

def new_file(*args):
    print(f'1 def new_file(*args): {class_file.file_open}, {class_file.file}')
    window.title("Untitled - PySider Editor")
    Textedit.delete(1.0, END)
    class_file.file_open = None
    class_file.file = None
    print(f'2 def new_file(*args): {class_file.file_open}, {class_file.file}')
#?    return class_file.file_open and class_file.file

def save_file(*args):
    print(f'2 def save_file(*args): {class_file.file_open}, {class_file.file}')
#    if class_file.file_open and class_file.file == None:
    if class_file.file_open is None and class_file.file is None:
        save_file_as()

    elif class_file.file_open and class_file.file != None:
        class_file.file = open(class_file.file_open, "w")
        class_file.file.write(Textedit.get(1.0, END))
        class_file.file.close()
#?        return class_file.file_open and class_file.file

    else:
        print("error")

def close_file(*args):
    window.title("Editor")
    Textedit.delete(1.0, END)
    class_file.file_open = None
    class_file.file = None
    return class_file.file_open and class_file.file


# MAIN
window = Tk()

# Window
window.title("Editor")
window.geometry('1250x680')
window["bg"] = "#333"

# Top menu
menu = Menu(window)
# File
file_items = Menu(menu)
file_items.add_command(label='New File                         Ctrl+N', command=new_file)
file_items.add_command(label='Open File                        Ctrl+O', command=open_file)
file_items.add_command(label='Close File                        Ctrl+W', command=close_file)
file_items.add_command(label='Close All                                ')
file_items.add_command(label='Save                               Ctrl+S', command=save_file)
file_items.add_command(label='Save All                                 ')
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_items)
window.config(menu=menu)

# Text
Textframe = Frame(window)
Textframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
Textedit = Text(Textframe, bg="#333", fg="white", font=('Arial', 14), insertbackground="white", insertwidth=3, wrap=WORD)  
Textedit.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

class_file = ClassFile()
print(f'func main: {class_file.file_open}, {class_file.file}')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ. Но когда я сделал экземпляр класса, ничего не зменилось
При объявлении экземпляра команда print сказала что переменные равны None, как и во время выполнения save_file, вместе с выводом "error". :/

Comment: @Innokentie напишите порядок действий, которые вы выполняете и что вы хотите получить в результате этих дейчтвий.

Comment: Хорошо. Мне нужно написать такие функции, чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на Save в меню, выполнялась функция save_file. И далее если какой либо файл был уже открыт и переменные file_open и file не равны None, файл просто сохранялся. А если эти переменные равны None, например когда редактор запустился, и выполнилась функция save_file появлялось окно asksaveasfilename() - Сохранить как.

Comment: @Innokentie я внес некоторые изменения, проверьте

Comment: Действительно, все работает. Мне хотелось сделать код по короче, теперь буду знать что такие сравнения невозможны. Спасибо вам большое, вы сильно мне помогли!

Answer (score 1):

> Здесь когда переменные `file_open` и `file` равны `None`, это не получается проверить

В этом условии `class_file.file_open and class_file.file == None` у вас проверяется не то, что оба поля равны `None`, а то что **первое поле истинно, а второе равно `None`**.

Нужно записать так: `class_file.file_open is None and class_file.file is None`. Или проверять что что оба поля ложны (например, в них `None` или пустые строки): `not class_file.file_open and not class_file.file`.

Про истинность или ложность значений см. например тут в разделе "Проверка истинности": [Инструкция if-elif-else, проверка истинности, трехместное выражение if/else](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/instrukciya-if-elif-else-proverka-istinnosti-trexmestnoe-vyrazhenie-ifelse.html)